# Are there strict boundaries for what you can do in the magical world?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

For this not to be a primary-opinion based question I want to get a canon-based answer to this question.

Does magic have rules or laws?

For instance:

1. Are there any boundaries beyond which magic cannot be done? Something that you can't get with magic? Something that magic won't work on? I mean like, can you make a woman pregnant using magic or make a tree grow a hundred times faster? Or maybe create a vacuum in an area?
2. Are there any limits to potion making? Can you make a potion that makes you permanently invisible?

Does Rowling ever mention any limits to what is possible and what is not in the Harry Potter world?

Comment: The limits of magic are not touched upon in great detail in canon. Certain fanfictions may offer what youre looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, yes, there is an example in the books, that you can't create love via a potion or spell.

> ‘Amortentia doesn’t really create love, of course. It is impossible to manufacture or imitate love. No, this will simply cause a powerful infatuation or obsession. It is probably the most dangerous and powerful potion in this room – oh yes,’ he said, nodding gravely at Malfoy and Nott, both of whom were smirking sceptically. ‘When you have seen as much of life as I have, you will not underestimate the power of obsessive love …’

That was said by Horace Slughorn to the Potions class in Half Blood Prince.

Comment: Working on finding the Merope quotes, I don't have HBP in front of me.

Comment: You've overlooked the big one - Magic can't bring people back from the dead.

Answer (score 0):

Let us not forget the five exceptions to Gamp's laws of elemental transfiguration (of which one is 'cannot create love').

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Fundemental Laws of Magic](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fundamental_Laws_of_Magic) but I only remember them being mentioned tangentially in Deathly Hallows, so there are clearly some limits that magic answers to in the Potterverse but the specifics are never, to my knowledge, made explicit.